# Mongodb does not recognize that field exists

Tags: mongodb

I am attempting to run a query on the field `screen_name`. It is contained in all of my documents. Whenever I look at the entries in mongo I can clearly see the field exists, compass can also see the field exists. However whenever I run any kind of find on `screen_name` it stops working. All other fields exist and return the correct number of documents.,

I've attempted to re-import the collection from a csv, I have also renamed the field in question in the csv itself before importing.

```
db.pages.find({screen_name:{$exists:true}}).count();
```

returns 0 results

```
db.pages.find({id:{$exists:true}}).count();
```

returns 231 results

```
db.pages.find({mission:{$exists:true}}).count();
```

returns 231 results

I expect the top query to also return 231 documents.

Comment: Please show a sample document.